# How to to install the ircmaxell/password-compat library via Composer

Tags: symfony, installation, composer-php, bcrypt

I'm using Symfony2 and I'm working on a login page. I want ot use the bcrypt algorithm, but to do so, I need to install the ircmaxell/password-compat library via Composer.

I looked up a couple of site, but I don't understand ANYTHING! I tried reading the Symfony documentation and it still didn't help.

If someone could give me the exact way to do that step by step, it would really be a great help. Assume that I don't know ANYTHING, so, please, be extremely specific in your instructions.

Here is the documentation:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
section: C) Encoding the User's Password

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three options if you want to install something via composer.

1. If you are using composer.phar:

   `php composer.phar require ircmaxell/password-compat`
2. If you did a global install and do not have the phar in that directory run this instead:

   `composer require ircmaxell/password-compat`
3. Edit composer.json and add this in require section:

   `"ircmaxell/password-compat": ">=1.0.*"`

   then simply do:

   `composer install`

Of course you have to remember to set encoding algorithm in Symfony security.yml, simply follow Symfony documentation to do that

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#c-encoding-the-user-s-password
https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md
https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I really don't get what to do. Where should I use composer? Aren't I suppose to download that library first so that composer could install it? In the documentation, it says i'm suppose to write: 
{
    "require": {
        ...
        "ircmaxell/password-compat": "~1.0.3"
    }
}
somewhere, but where?

Comment: I tried to do what you said, but when I execute the command  composer require ircmaxell/password-compat,  I get this error: an error occured when executing the ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command.

Comment: Thats fine, sometimes this happen. Try running

php app/console cache:clear -e prod && php app/console cache:clear

and if that won't help, delete cache manually: rm -rf app/cache

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use anything that is managed by Composer, you should include the autoloader right at the start of your script.

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php'; // adjust the path depending on where your script is located
```

After this line got executed, you should be able to use any class or function provided by the Composer packages you installed.

For ircmaxell/password-compat this means you can directly use the PHP functions without any further action in your code. This has nothing to do with Symfony itself.